# Write UUID as text in cassandra with node.js

Tags: node.js, cassandra, uuid

I have a column in cassandra table user_id which is type text. I'm trying to pass generated uuid which is packed as string to be written in the table. When I do this I get an error:

```
Not a valid text value, expected String obtained uuid
```

I tried with using hints when I pass parameter:

```
{hint: 'String', value: data['userId']}
```

But I still get an error:

```
[TypeError: Not a valid text value, expected String obtained { hint: 'String',
  value: 'e738922c-2277-45fd-aa94-7f5e7a189084' }]
```

I'm using cassandra version: 2.2.4

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you generate the uuid? Are you sure it's actually a string? What does `typeof(uuid)` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I was using:

```
client.execute(query, parameters, {prepare: true}, function(err, result)
```

When I removed {prepare: true} it started to work ok.